# how to loop through all setters of .net object

Tags: c#, properties, setter

I'm working with an object from a 3rd party library (**meaning I can't modify the structure of it**). This object has 12 string setter properties named HI01, HI02,...HI12:

```
public string HI01 {get; set;}
public string HI02 {get; set;}
...
public string HI12 {get; set;}
```

How can I loop through these and assign values, preferably without using reflection? Is there a way to put references to the properties into a collection and iterate over it?

Comment: Why not just make it a collection or list in the first place?

Comment: Unless you make a lambda for setting each property, reflection is your only option that can preserve this structure. That said, don't preserve this structure. Do what @ChrisLaplante said.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I'm working with a 3rd party lib that I can't modify.

Comment: The more information you add, the more sure I get that reflection is your only option.

Comment: Then just make a small mapper utility method which converts between a list/collection and the 3rd party properties.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have an `object o` of your third party library:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in o.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    pi.SetValue(o, "Your Value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your properties like this, no need to get *setter* method:

```
var properties = typeof(yourType)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("HI"));
```

Then use `SetValue` method to assign them to a value.